# How to make this jquery animation start when in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want this animation to start only when it is in the viewport. How could I achieve this? As of now the animation works wonderfully, yet by the time it gets scrolled into view, it is already over.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="by-numb-1 by-numb-text hide"><p class="by-numb-1 hidden-load 
  text-light text-center"><span class="by-numb-numb">15643</span>Projects 
  Completed</p></div>  
</div>



<script>
      $('.by-numb-numb').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 6000 ,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    })
   </script>
```

Could anyone help me figure it out?
I want the output to be 15,643.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add some more details on what this is supposed to do, and what is the current output?

Comment: @gparyani, I edited just now.